# 'JsonTable' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to get an Json value into the json table in react but it is throwing an error "'JsonTable' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef".
What should i do? Is there Some file i need to import.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
export default class SearchHistory extends Component {
  constructor()
  {
      super();
      this.state={data:null};
  }
        componentDidMount () {

            this.data().then(data => {
                const self=this;
                this.setState({data:data});
            });

        }
        columns() {
            return[
                {key:'name',label:'Name'},
                {key:'age',label:'Age'},
                {key:'color',label:'Color',cell:(obj,key) => {
                    return <span>{obj[key]} </span>;
                }}
                ];
        }

        data() {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
         resolve([
                 {name:'sssss',age:20,color:'red'}
                    ]);

        });       
    }

        render() {
            <JsonTable rows={this.state.data} columns={this.columns()} />
    return (
            <div>Loading.... </div>
          )


    }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Faced same issue,  moved on to material UI :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late answer:

I tried the JsonTable, but i think it uses the deprecated "React.createClass" in the library so it doesn't work in React 15...

here is a working samle in react 0.14.8:

hope this helps :)

```js
/*
Simplest example for react-json-table.

To see the customization options visit
https://github.com/arqex/react-json-table
*/

var items = [
  { name: 'Louise', age: 27, color: 'red' },
  { name: 'Margaret', age: 15, color: 'blue'},
  { name: 'Lisa', age:34, color: 'yellow'}
];

React.render(
  <JsonTable rows={ items } />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/arqex/react-json-table/master/build/react-json-table.min.js"></script>
```

I think you need to import react-json-table from : https://github.com/arqex/react-json-table
because react doesn't know JsonTable.

-> to do so:

add react-json-table to your project:

```
npm install react-json-table --save
```

then simply add at the top of your file:

```
import {JsonTable} from 'react-json-table';
```

Comment: Yeah i did tried importing the {JsonTable}. But it throws an error "TypeError: React.createClass is not a function". As far as i know know there isn't a file name JsonTable to import from the npm package. Sorry for the delayed comment.

Comment: there should be a folder named react-json-table in your node_modules folder to import...(after you did npm install...)

how did you import i think? maybe there is a little Type fault, because the React.createClass should not throw that error: may just a missing character

Comment: Can you help me with a sample that works... I'm totally stuck in it.... even just a slightest modification would help...Thanks...

Comment: Did this sample helped or could you solved the problem?

Comment: Actually i'm now using a plain old html table... I did tried using JSON table but it didn't qork previously.... I'll try it out and let you know..Thank you..... @x1x